# How can I assign data context in onCreated

Tags: javascript, meteor

How can I assign data context in onCreated (replace the whole context)?
Following does not work:

```
Template.mine.onCreated(function() {
  this.data = function() { return "MyData"; }
})
```

While following does:

```
Template.mine.onCreated(function() {
  this.data.myData = function() { return "MyData"; }
})
```

I would like to replace the whole context. 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.data` is immutable. To replace the data context either wrap your `mine` template and pass the correct data. E.g.;

```
<template name="mineWrap">
  {{> mine mydata}}
</template>
```

Or, store your data directly on the template instance. E.g.;

```
Template.mine.onCreated(function () {
  this._myData = 'data';
});

Template.mine.helpers({
  myData: function () {
    return Template.instance()._myData;
  }
});
```

Comment: Was afraid that this is the case. Oh well, moving on ;)

Answer (score 1):

Cannot you use : `Template.dynamic`? [Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic)

```
{{> Template.dynamic template='TEMPLATE_NAME' data=CONTEXT }}
```